# TypedArray and Enums

Tags: java, android, typed-arrays

I'm trying to create my first android app and now I've got into a design problem. I'm making a jokes app(all the jokes are to be stored offline) and i'm not sure how to deal with putting the jokes and then retrieving them. I found out about TypedArrays, which would seem like a good idea, but my Joke class contains enums, and I'm not sure if I can set enums from the TypedArray.

**jokes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="texts">
    <item>Sure, white people can't say the "n word" but, atleast we can say phrases like,"Thanks for the warning, Officer" and, "Hey, Dad."</item>
    <item>I cheated on my girlfriend once. I was playing monopoly and I took some money from the bank when she wasn't looking.
        Then I went upstairs and fucked her sister.</item>
    <item>'Yo Momma' jokes are old and worn out. Just like… Yo Momma.</item>
</array>
<array name="category">
    <item>OFFENSIVE</item>
    <item>ANTIJOKES</item>
    <item>YO_MOMMA</item>
</array>
<array name="length">
    <item>SHORT</item>
    <item>MEDIUM</item>
    <item>SHORT</item>
</array>

</resources>
```

**Joke.java**

```
    //TODO add more joke categories
private enum CATEGORY{OFFENSIVE,YO_MAMMA,ANTIJOKES}
public enum LENGTH{SHORT,MEDIUM,LONG}
private String mText;
//I'm not sure about this one, is just a placeholder for the audio file of the joke
private File mAudioFile;
private CATEGORY mCategory;
private LENGTH mLength;



public Joke(String text,CATEGORY category,LENGTH length){
    mText = text;
    mCategory = category;
    mLength = length;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public Joke getJoke(int index){
    Resources resources = getResources();
    TypedArray text = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.texts);
    TypedArray category = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.category);
    TypedArray length = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.length);

    Joke joke = new Joke(text,category,length);
}
```

I'm open to suggestions to do this in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use JSON. You can store your jokes as JSON in files and use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to unmarshal the Jokes into POJOs. Also you should change `File mAudioFile` to `String mAudioFile` and detect audio file by name to avoid problems with JSON marshaling/unmarshaling.

**Update**
Your POJO can be looks like this:

```
public class Joke {
    private String mText;
    private String mAudio;
    private CATEGORY category;
    private LENGTH length;

    public Joke(String mText, String mAudio, CATEGORY category, LENGTH length) {
        this.mText = mText;
        this.mAudio = mAudio;
        this.category = category;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String getmText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public void setmText(String mText) {
        this.mText = mText;
    }

    public String getmAudio() {
        return mAudio;
    }

    public void setmAudio(String mAudio) {
        this.mAudio = mAudio;
    }

    public CATEGORY getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(CATEGORY category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public LENGTH getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(LENGTH length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
}
```

And your JSON sample is:

```
{
  "mText": "text",
  "mAudio": "audio file path",
  "category": "YO_MAMMA",
  "length": "LONG"
}
```

Comment: Can i easily use enums with json? Is there any way to type json easier than in notepad?

Comment: Yes you can, I've updated the answer with samples. Also I prefer this tool to work with JSON http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/